# Entity Model cannot accept View without id?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, entity-model

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) 
PERCENT country_Code, country_Name

FROM         dbo.Location
```

> Message   1   The table/view 'mixtapez.dbo.View_Select_Country' does not
>   have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the
>   definition was created as a read-only
>   table/view.   E:\1C#asp.net\vuziq\vuziq\Projects\BannerSystem\WebBannerSystem\WebBannerSystem\Models\Model1.edmx  0   0   WebBannerSystem

The view works on others languages, so I dont want get `Id` by distinct, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It is just an informative message that Entity Framework created what it thinks is the primary key because **any Entity Framework entity must have a primary key** (that is .NET key, not SQL key). If you have read-only entity, the autogenerated key will probably work just fine for you. To be extra safe (and remove any chance the key does not work correctly), you should use `NoTracking` option for queries on this entity.

If you use `.Distinct()` in LINQ query that will go into your SQL query - the key Entity Framework uses does not play any role.

Comment: At moment I give up the entity, because this worked well on SQL database connetion but I will try your way.